# Indistinguishability of exponentially close distributions

Tags: algorithms, probability-theory

Let $D_{1}$ and $D_{2}$ be two probability distributions over $n$-bit strings such that the total variation distance between them is $\mathcal{O}\left(1/{2^{n}}\right)$. Given as input a polynomial number of samples from any one of the distributions, the task is to output $1$ if the samples come from the first distribution and $0$ if they come from the second one. I am trying to show that no polynomial-time algorithm (even with bounded error) can do this task.

Intuitively, it should be very clear that two distributions that are exponentially close are indistinguishable. But how do I formalize the intuition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the key. Let $A \otimes B$ be the distribution corresponding to a sample from $A$ and an independent sample from $B$, and denote total variation distance by $d_{TV}$. Then

$$d_{TV}(A_1 \otimes A_2, B_1 \otimes B_2) \leq d_{TV}(A_1,B_1) + d_{TV}(A_2,B_2)$$

We can see this using the $L_1$ formula for $d_{TV}$:
\begin{align}
d_{TV}(A_1\otimes A_2,B_1\otimes B_2) &=
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{x_1,x_2} |\Pr[A_1=x_1]\Pr[A_2=x_2] - \Pr[B_1=x_1]\Pr[B_2=x_2]| \\ &\leq
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{x_1,x_2} |\Pr[A_1=x_1]\Pr[A_2=x_2] - \Pr[B_1=x_1]\Pr[A_2=x_2]| \\ &+
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{x_1,x_2} |\Pr[B_1=x_1]\Pr[A_2=x_2] - \Pr[B_1=x_1]\Pr[B_2=x_2]| \\ &=
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{x_2} \Pr[A_2=x_2] \sum_{x_1} |\Pr[A_1=x_1] - \Pr[B_1=x_1]| \\ &+
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{x_1} \Pr[B_1=x_1] \sum_{x_2} |\Pr[A_2=x_2] - \Pr[B_2=x_2]| \\ &=
\sum_{x_2} \Pr[A_2=x_2] d_{TV}(A_1,B_1) + \sum_{x_1} \Pr[B_1=x_1] d_{TV}(A_2,B_2) \\ &=
d_{TV}(A_1,B_1) + d_{TV}(A_2,B_2).
\end{align}

Now let $D^{\otimes n}$ denote $n$ independent samples from $D$. The above inequality shows that
$$
d_{TV}(D_1^{\otimes m}, D_2^{\otimes m}) \leq m d_{TV}(D_1,D_2).
$$
Let $E$ be the event that your algorithm outputs "$D_1$". The definition of $d_{TV}$ guarantees that
$$
|\Pr_{D_1^{\otimes m}}[E] - \Pr_{D_2^{\otimes m}}[E]| \leq d_{TV}(D_1^{\otimes m}, D_2^{\otimes m}) \leq m d_{TV}(D_1,D_2).
$$
Here $\Pr_D$ denotes that the samples in the algorithm are generated from the distribution $D$.

We deduce that an algorithm with advantage $\delta$ must use at least $\delta/d_{TV}(D_1,D_2)$ samples.

Comment: How does the definition of  $d_{TV}$ guarantee the first inequality in the last line?

Comment: My definition of total variation distance is the maximum, over all events $E$, of this quantity.